# Scatter Graph In C# With PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

There is an input of points with size of n like below:

S = {x1,y1,x2,y2,...,xn,yn}

I want to display scatter graph of S sequence in a picture box. So for transforming them into picture box dimensions, I have normalized them and multiplied them by width and height of picture box with respecting picture box left and top:

```
waveData= wave.GetWaveData();
normalizedData = GetSignedNormalized();
n = normalizedData.Count;
picW = pictureBox1.Width;
picH = pictureBox1.Height;
picL = pictureBox1.Left;
picT = pictureBox1.Top;
normalizedInPictureBox = new List<float>();

for (int i=0;i< n; i +=2)
{
    float px = normalizedData[i];
    float py = normalizedData[i+1];
    px = px * (picW - picL);
    py = py * (picH - picT) ;                
    normalizedInPictureBox.Add(px);
    normalizedInPictureBox.Add(py);
}
```

Normalize Method is also:

```
public List<float> GetSignedNormalized()
{
    List<float> data = new List<float>();
    short max = waveData.Max();
    int m = waveData.Count;
    for(int i=0;i< m; i++)
    {
        data.Add((float)waveData[i] / (float)max);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Now I am thinking normalizedInPictureBox List contains vertices in the range of picture box, and here is the code for drawing them on picture box:

In the paint method of picture box:

```
Graphics gr = e.Graphics;
gr.Clear(Color.Black);
for(int i=0;i< n; i +=2)
{
    float x = normalizedInPictureBox[i] ;
    float y = normalizedInPictureBox[i+1];

    gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, new RectangleF(x, y, 2.25f, 2.25f));
}
```

But the result is shown below:

[image]

I don't Know whats going wrong here , but I think the graph should be horizontal not diagonal ,the desire result is something like this:

[image]

I know that I can transform it to center of picture box after this. but How can change my own result to the desire one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you made sure that the data in `normalizedData` is correct?

Comment: Did you doublecheck the original data? I suggest drawing them (more or less) unscaled into a bitmap you can then display in the PBox with size mode = zoom.. Also. How many data points do you have? Are the two images about the same wave range?

Comment: @Jens Yes I have updated the method which normalized the data , I have test them in Excel , result is same as original

Comment: @TaW , I have drawn them witch Excel chart tools , every thing goes ok. also data length is not important.

Comment: _short max = waveData.Max();_ why short only to cast to float?? - Is wavedata short? You didn't show us.. - Not telling us about the size makes it harder to evaluate the images.

Comment: @Taw , the x1,y1,...xn,yn are short

Comment: You say that your data is x1,y1,x2,y2.  But I'm pretty sure you are processing just y1,y2,y3,...   Where would the x coordinates come from?

Comment: Consider that plotting (y1,y2) then (y3,y4) would create a diagonal line exactly as shown.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, what is your logic for this , I am plotting either x's or y's,

Comment: If you are plotting waveaudio data (which is what that "desired result" looks like) you should know that it's periodic samples, not scatter.  Proper plotting of periodic samples would have a consistent horizontal density -- yours doesn't, which makes me believe you are using y values as the x coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why your code doesn't work correctly without having a look at the actual data and playing around with it, but having done chart drawing before, I suggest you go the full way and clearly define your axis ranges and do proper interpolating. It get's much clearer from there.

Here is what I came up with

```
static Bitmap DrawChart(float[] Values, int Width, int Height)
{
    var n = Values.Count();
    if (n % 2 == 1) throw new Exception("Invalid data");

    //Split the data into lists for easy access
    var x = new List<float>();
    var y = new List<float>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i += 2)
    {
        x.Add(Values[i]);
        y.Add(Values[i + 1]);
    }

    //Chart axis limits, change here to get custom ranges like -1,+1
    var minx = x.Min();
    var miny = y.Min();
    var maxx = x.Max();
    var maxy = y.Max();

    var dxOld = maxx - minx;
    var dyOld = maxy - miny;

    //Rescale the y-Range to add a border at the top and bottom
    miny -= dyOld * 0.2f;
    maxy += dyOld * 0.2f;

    var dxNew = (float)Width;
    var dyNew = (float)Height;

    //Draw the data
    Bitmap res = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(res))
    {
        g.Clear(Color.Black);
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Count; i++)
        {
            //Calculate the coordinates
            var px = Interpolate(x[i], minx, maxx, 0, dxNew);
            var py = Interpolate(y[i], miny, maxy, 0, dyNew);
            //Draw, put the ellipse center around the point
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.ForestGreen, px - 1.0f, py - 1.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f);
        }
    }
    return res;
}

static float Interpolate(float Value, float OldMin, float OldMax, float NewMin, float NewMax)
{
    //Linear interpolation
    return ((NewMax - NewMin) / (OldMax - OldMin)) * (Value - OldMin) + NewMin;
}
```

It should be relatively self explanatory. You may consider drawing lines instead of single points, that depends on the look and feel you want to achive. Draw other chart elements to your liking.

**Important:** The y-Axis is actually inversed in the code above, so positive values go down, negative go up, it is scaled like the screen coordinates. You'll figure out how to fix that :-)

Example with 5000 random-y points (x is indexed):
[image]